# Restoring an old config file

Tags: raspbian-stretch, update

I recently did an update/upgrade (the first one with this sd-Card) and the configuration files were overwritten and backed up to /home/pi/oldconffiles/

How do I restore all these files so that they are used?

Comment: your post is unclear .... you say that the files were overwritten and then they were backed up, which would mean that the backup contains the new files ... do you mean to say that the update failed to do the backup before overwriting the files?

Comment: This is when you go back and use Win32DiskImager to rewrite the card from your saved image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Raspbian November 2018](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/raspbian-update-november-2018/) changed the configuration. 
>   *Most of the desktop components have now been modified so that they correctly read the global configuration files, and for future releases, we are going to try to just modify the global versions of these files and not touch the local ones.*
>
> Initially you will lose your customisations and this may or may not be the best approach.

I find this behaviour annoying (and lazy programming - just overwriting old files).

Ideally you should check for differences (there is occasionally an incompatible change, which requires manual update), but most often the following undoes the damage.

```
cp /home/pi/oldconffiles/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/* /home/pi/.config/lxsession/LXDE-pi/
cp /home/pi/oldconffiles/.config/openbox/* /home/pi/.config/openbox
cp /home/pi/oldconffiles/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE-pi/* /home/pi/.config/pcmanfm/LXDE-pi/
```